# pandas dataframe update values using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with id and date:

```
data = [{'id': 'a', 'date': 1, 'value':3}, {'id':'b', 'date': 1, 'value': 30},
    {'id': 'a', 'date': 2, 'value':5}, {'id':'b', 'date': 2, 'value': 20}] 
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to loop over each date and do some calculation with value column to get an adjusted_value column:

```
for idx, daily_df in test_df.groupby('date'):
    daily_df['adj_value'] = some functions
```

I have two questions:

1. I am getting a warning from this: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`
2. I want to add the adj_value column to the original test_df

Comment: update: for 2, just found out that i can do test_df.loc[test_df['date'] == idx, 'adj_value'] = adj_values. It is one way, not sure if it's a good way though

Comment: Depending on what kind of calculation you want to do, you can calculate totals, averages and counts by date with `test_df.groupby('date')['value'].agg(['sum','mean','count'])`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to loop over `groupby()` results.  `NamedAgg()` does what you want.  I've sythesized a function for purpose of example,  normally I'd use a built in function or a `lambda` function

```
data = [{'id': 'a', 'date': 1, 'value':3}, {'id':'b', 'date': 1, 'value': 30},
    {'id': 'a', 'date': 2, 'value':5}, {'id':'b', 'date': 2, 'value': 20}] 
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def myfunc(x):
    x = list(x)
    if len(x)>1: return x[0] * x[1]
    else: return x[0]

test_df.groupby("date").agg(adj_value=pd.NamedAgg(column="value", aggfunc=myfunc))
```

**output**

```
      adj_value
date           
1            90
2           100
```

Comment: i guess i wasn't very clear. i do not want aggregated values, but rather i want to add an adjust_value column for each row. Let's say for this example, I want to add a column that is:
1. for date 1, add up values. if total is less than 50, then adj_value = value, otherwise adj_value = value / 2
2. then for the next date, repeat the same thing, except now instead of 50, the benchmark is sum(adj_values in date 1)

Comment: `groupby()` immediately means you are working with aggregates.... if all you want to do is define a new column that has conditional logic ("let's say" is conditional??) just use assign with a numpy where `test_df.assign(adj_value=lambda x: np.where(x["id"]=="a", x["date"]*x["value"], x["value"]*30))`